# IIS web response connection forcibly closed issue

Tags: c#, .net, iis, httpwebrequest, httpresponse

I have client desktop app and web service deployed on external server (IIS). Communication between them is based on HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse.
This code was working fine on IIS 8.0 and after upgrading it to IIS 8.5 sending response back to the client stopped working. The following exception is thrown on client side:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection :  
>  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host. ---> 
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:  
> An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
>    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags) 
>    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) 
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size) 
>    at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination,
>   Int32 bufferSize) 
>    at
>   Test.TestHttpService.GetResponseString(HttpWebResponse response)

On the server side no exception is thrown. Wireshark on server and Fiddler on client machine also give no clue. IIS trace log shows that all data has been successfully sent to the client

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqmD9.png)

Client side code:

```
    public static string GetResponse(string serviceUrl, string resourceUrl, string method, string xmlRequestBody, string authorization, string connectionName)
    {
        string responseMessage = null;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Concat(serviceUrl, resourceUrl)) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request != null)
        {
            request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.Method = method;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
            request.Timeout = int.MaxValue;
            //request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorization);
            request.Headers.Add("ConnectionName", connectionName);
        }

        if (xmlRequestBody != null)
        {
            byte[] requestBodyBytes = TBCCompressionService.Zip(xmlRequestBody.ToString());
            request.ContentLength = requestBodyBytes.Length;
            if (request.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(requestBodyBytes, 0, requestBodyBytes.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        if (request != null)
        {
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
            try
            {
                var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    responseMessage = GetResponseString(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    responseMessage = response.StatusDescription;
                }
            }
            catch(WebException ex)
            {
                var httpResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                if (httpResponse != null
                    && httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
                {
                    responseMessage = GetResponseString(ex.Response as HttpWebResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return responseMessage;
    }
private static string GetResponseString(HttpWebResponse response)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        if(response != null)
        {
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (responseStream != null)
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        //this is the line when above exception is thrown.
                        responseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                        result = TBCCompressionService.UnZip(memoryStream.ToArray());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Server side code:

```
public static void Send(string responseContent, HttpStatusCode? httpStatus)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    int waitCounter = 1000;
    if (response.IsClientConnected)
    {
        response.Clear();
        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.Buffer = true;

        if (httpStatus != null)
        {
            response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatus.Value;
        }

        if (responseContent == null
            || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responseContent))
        {
            response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent;
        }
         else
        {
            byte[] responseContentZip = Zip(responseContent);
            int responseContentLength = responseContentZip.Length;
            response.ContentType = "text/xml";
            response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", responseContentLength.ToString());
            response.BinaryWrite(responseContentZip);
        }
            response.Flush();
            //If this sleep is not present exception is thrown on the client side
            //Unable to read data from the transport connection : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitCounter);
            response.Close();
            response.End();
    }
    else
    {
        logger.Error("Client was no longer connected to remote server. Response wasn't sent.");
    }
}
```

Very weird thing is that sleeping AppPool thread helps and lets response reach the client successfully.
It seems to me that Flush operation doesn't end before connection is closed, I looked for some clues in **System.Web.dll** code but nothing was pointing that Flush in this case is executed asynchronously or something during execution breaks connection.

Comment: Did you look the event logs ?

Comment: Yes I did and there is also no clue what is going on with this connection.

Answer (score 0):

U CAN USE Limiting the number of service points

> **
>   webRequest.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = 1;

**